# How to "silently" send an email?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, email

How can I "silently" (without user's intervention needed) send an email from a C# Windows 8 "Metro"/Store/Modern UI app?

### UPDATE

Based on what I glean from here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/winappswithcsharp/thread/393a123f-674c-4b44-af87-9963053f42fd

It may be that I can use my app as a Share Source, targeting the built-in email client, and IT will send my email on. Make sense?

### UPDATE 2

I'm thinking Raw Notifications (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d) might be in my future.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you want to do?

Comment: I want to send an email from a "Metro" app to somebody using a Windows 8 Phone. Both the sending and the receiving of the email will be non-intrusive on the part of the Metro user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRT doesn't include the **System.Net.Mail** namespace, so if you want to directly send an email from your app, you need to manually connect to your mail web service, opening a socket to the SMTP port, etc.

Otherwise, you need to call something like a WCF service that receives parameters and sends the mail.